# Getting Sitecore Field with Web API

Tags: javascript, sitecore

I have a question regarding the Sitecore Item Web API.
I have this JSON extract result when I call my Sitecore Web API:

```
{"statusCode":200,
[...]
"Version":1,
"Fields":{
"{0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450}":{
"Name":"Phone number",
"Type":"Single-Line Text",
"Value":"XXXX"},
"{FA170F50-43FA-49B7-9AB1-9B4047DDBC2C}":{
"Name":"Fax",
"Type":"Number",
"Value":"YYYYYY"}
```

What I would like to do is to get the phone number Value field, or the Fax value field, directly, without looping through each GUID testing if the Name == "Phone Number" and then getting the Value etc...

I already have this JavaScript code but it is with this foreach loop, and it's not really fast.

```
 function extractPhoneNumber(siteCoreFieldsList) {
        var phoneNumberFieldValue;
        $jq.each(siteCoreFieldsList, function (index, value) {
            if (value.Name == "Phone number") {
                phoneNumberFieldValue = value.Value;
            }
        });
        return phoneNumberFieldValue;
    }
```

Anyone has a work around or something more clean ?
Thanks a lot for your help. Regards.

Comment: why not use `indexOf()`?

Comment: You're not storing FieldIDs? You should really be referencing the template field directly and not relying on what it's named (what if admin changes it?)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of a "best practice", you should be storing the field IDs somewhere any using them to get to the value.

However, given you're already creating function with the specific purpose of getting a value you could place the IDs there.

```
function extractFax(sitecoreFieldList){
  return sitecoreFieldList['{FA170F50-43FA-49B7-9AB1-9B4047DDBC2C}'] || '';
}
function extractPhoneNumber(sitecoreFieldList){
  return sitecoreFieldList['{0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450}'] || '';
}
```